# What is difference between SDK tool and Build Tool in Android SDK Components?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to know the exact difference between SDK Tool and Build Tools.According to some article and answer, both tools are used to build apk. I went through officials document but did't get anything.

Please provide difference/Detail of all Android SDK components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SDK TOOL** : A software development toolkit (SDK) is a set of software tools and programs provided by hardware and software vendors that developers can use to build applications for specific platforms.

**BUILD TOOL** : Build tools are programs that automate the creation of executable applications from source code. Building incorporates compiling, linking and packaging the code into a usable or executable form.

The **Platform** tools are more specifically suited to the version of Android that you want to target. Generally, it is best to install the latest Platform tools, after first installation though, you need to keep your Platform-tools constantly updated.

The **Android Debug Bridge (ADB)** is a program that allows you to communicate with any Android device. It relies on Platform-tools in order to understand the Android version that is being used.

The **Android emulator** is what lets you test and monitor apps on a PC, without necessarily needing to have a device available

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding build tool will control the overall build process and will finally generate an APK using the SDK tools. Build toll uses zip align tool to optimize the app to use minimal memory and will use the app signer which signs the APK for verification. It can also use other additional tools for the build process.

I agree that names are confusing because the overall build systems are being developed over the years and new tools are introduced and sometimes old names are modified. For example, Build tools were under Platform-tools previously but later it got more importance and become a separate tool.

Comment: then what is the description of SDK tool?

Comment: I want to know diffrence of both term SDK tool and Build tool as both are representing in Android Sdk component .